# Java Android Fade Music with MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, media-player, fadein, fadeout

I made a very basic app that plays a song from MediaPlayer. There are 3 buttons. One assigns the song already in my raw folder. The other is to start the music. The last will stop the music.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MediaPlayer mPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void song1 (View v) {
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wordplay);
}

public void onClickStart(View v) {
    mPlayer.start();
}

public void onClickStop(View v) {
    mPlayer.stop();
    mPlayer.release();
}
}
```

I want my music to fade in when I click "start" and fade out when I click "stop".

Thinking it through, maybe I should create another thread that executes each x seconds? And then with each repetition I would bring the volume up from 0 for the "start" and bring the volume down to 0 for the "stop"? I'm not sure how I would execute that though. Then I'm guessing I would have to figure out what volume my device is playing at as well, right?

Any help with codes is appreciated! I'm still new to coding. Thanks!

Comment: Your logic using a Thread is good i think . The `Thread` can run some iterations and sleep for some duration and on each iteration low the volume by 1 or 2 or the value your want . Is there a `setVolume(x);` method on `MediaPlayer` class ? You need not to care about the device volume , cause it is different from `MediaPlayer` volume ....